# Finding z values and probabilities in standard normal table

Tags: binomial-distribution

There are 90 people in the restaurant.  The probability of someone ordering a drink with food is 60%.  Use Normal approximation of Binomial Distribution to answer the following 6 questions.

1. What is the mean of the Normal distribution?
2. What is the standard deviation of the normal distribution?
3. What is the probability that exactly 50 people will order a drink?
4. What the probability that more than 50 people will order a drink?
5. What is the probability that less than 50 people will order a drink?
6. What is the probability that between 52 or more and 56 or less people will order a drink?

1 and 2 I get (54 and 4.64758, respectively).  3 - 6 not so much, especially how to look up z values and probabilities in the standard normal table.  I only have access to the 0 to z normal distribution table, like page one here:

http://chemeng.iisc.ac.in/venu/tables.pdf

Thanks.

Comment: Please express your gratitude (if there's any) via the way of upvoting or clicking the accept (green check mark) for the answer for this and your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to standardize the random variable. Let $X$ the binomial distributed random variable then

$$P(X\leq x)\approx\Phi\left( \frac{x+0.5-\mu}{\sigma}  \right)$$

with $\mu=90\cdot 0.6=54$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{90\cdot 0.6\cdot 0.4}\approx 4.64758$. It confirms your results.

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution and $+0.5$ is the continuity correction factor. Now some hints. At $5)$ I demonstrate how to evaluate $P(X\leq x)$.

**3)** $P(X=x)=P(X\leq x)-P(X\leq x-1)$ In your case $x=50$ and $x-1=49$

**4)** $P(X> 50)=1-P(X\leq 50)$

---

**5)** $P(X< 50)=P(X\leq 49)$

$P(X\leq 49)\approx \Phi\left( \frac{49+0.5-54}{4.64758}  \right)=\Phi\left( -0.97\right)=1-\Phi\left( 0.97 \right)$

Now you look at [the table](http://chemeng.iisc.ac.in/venu/tables.pdf) and look for the probability, where $\Phi(0.97)=p$ This is at the row with z=0.9 and the column with $0.07$. The value is $0.3340$ and we have to add $0.5$ since $P(Z<0)=0.5$: 0.834

Thus $P(X<50)\approx 1-0.834=0.166$

Using the binomial distribution confirms the approximation:

$$\sum_{x=0}^{49} {{90} \choose x} 0.6^x\cdot 0.4^{90-x}=0.1663$$

---

**6)** $P(52\leq X\leq 56)=P(X\leq 56)-P(X\leq 51)$